# "AFNetworking.h" file not found in .pch file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, afnetworking

I installed AFNetworking using cocoapods. And then I included AFNetworking.h file in Prefix.pch file. Now while building my app it shows "AFNetworking.h" file not found error. I think it's an error related to path.

Thanks.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding if you're sure it should work.

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Remove it from the .pch file and add it manually where you need it. I had the same issue with a different file and cocapods.

Comment: go to manage schemes delete scheme and add scheme. Now clean and rebuild it.

Comment: Can you paste your include line?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This happened to me when I updated to AFNetworking 2.5.0 from 2.4.1 through Cocoapods.

In XCode go to Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes. There delete the project (maintaining the pods) and add the project again. It worked for me.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: That didn't work for me. Remove it from the .pch file and add it manually where you need it. Then it worked.

Comment: This also cured the same problem but with GoogleAnalytics "GAI.h not found".

Answer (score 4):

for me replacing

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
```

to

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What **always works** for me in most of the cases (including this case as well):

1. **Delete the 'Pods' folder** from the project directory (just cmd+delete the folder in Finder).
2. Do **`pod install`** via terminal in the project's directory.

Answer (score 0):

After updating pod's to (pod 'AFNetworking', '3.0') I was facing same issue.

Replacing

> ### #import "AFNetworking.h"

With

> ### @import AFNetworking;

solved this problem!